# Simple JQuery Timed Image Rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

For some reason, the following has no effect. This is most likely a product of me not having any sleep and the solution is probably very simple...

JS:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.js"> </script>
    <script>
        function swapImages(){
          var $active = $('#switch .active');
          var $next = ($('#switch .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#switch .active').next() : $('#switch img:first');
          $active.fadeOut(function(){
              $active.removeClass('active');
              $next.fadeIn().addClass('active');
          });
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
          // Run our swapImages() function every 5secs
          setInterval('swapImages()', 5000);
        }
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="switch"><img src="images/chalk.jpg" class="active" /><img src="images/students.jpg" /></div>
```

CSS:

```
#switch{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 996px;
    height: 374px;
}

#switch img{
    display:none;
}

#switch img.active{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bDPA5/), it works fine for me.

The only thing I have changed (besides adding colors for presentation purposes) is I have changed your `setInterval` call to this:

```
 setInterval(swapImages, 5000);
```

Generally, it is not a good practice to pass a string to `setInterval`. It works like `eval`, which we all know is evil :). Pass a function to it. If you really want to do more, use a closure (which is unnecessary here).

Answer (score 1):

there's a plugin for that ;)

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/lite/

it's really light weight, and gives some nice options for the animation to switch the images.

Comment: Good find! Nice plugin, however, its not as light weight as what I wrote...and what I have there is all I need so I'd like to get it working if possible. I'm just stumped as to why this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `);` at the end of `document.ready` function, and change the `setTnterval` to the actual function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
              // Run our swapImages() function every 5secs
              setInterval(swapImages, 1000);
            });
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/4d6X5/